# Oracle Apex, when a report with sql is created, how do i get it return after entering in to a text box?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to use the wildcard character within the where clause for a report based on a query.

The user will enter the criteria through a textbox and here is the query I have developed.

```
select JOID,
       JOBNAME,
       JOBTYPE,
       MACHINE,
       JOB_BOX,
       JOBDOC,
  from CYCLE_JOB_VIEW
 where JOB_NAME LIKE :P1_SEARCHTEXTBOX
```

When I run the report I get the error below:

> ERR-1777: Page 1 provided no page to branch to. Please report this
>   error to your application administrator.

I am using Apex version 3.2

Answer (score 3):

When the user enters some search criteria and hits Enter (or clicks a button), their browser generally submits the page to the server and Apex directs them to the appropriate page as defined.

In your case, you are getting ERR-1777 because your page doesn't specify what page to branch to. You probably just need to add a branch back to page 1, so that the search term is applied to the report on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a installation of Apex 3.2 and the following was developed on 4.2.x using the wizard but I believe it should work for you.

First here is the report without any criteria:

[image]

Now here is report after some criteria has been entered and the button "Go" pressed:

[image]

This functionality is obtained by using the following query (which has been created by Apex):

```
select * 
from (select "JOB_ID",
             "JOB_TITLE",
             "MIN_SALARY",
             "MAX_SALARY"
        from #OWNER#.OEHR_JOBS)
        where (instr(upper("JOB_TITLE"),upper(nvl(:P2_REPORT_SEARCH,"JOB_TITLE"))) > 0)
```

The branch error you are seeing, probably means that you need to either create a branch back to your page or the existing branch is pointing to an invalid location.